# best way to calculate the result of a multiple uitextfields

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I'm implementing an app that has a button that will sum the content of 4 uitextfields. My issue is " How to know which uitextfields is empty? "

I want to make sure that no uitextfield is ignored if it has value when the button is pressed.
would a normal if-statement do the trick? for example :

```
if(textfield1 is not empty && textfield2 is not empty &&... && textfield4 is not empty) {

// add them together

}else if (choose one textfield to check if its empty) {

// sign the empty textfield to 0 and add the rest

} else if (choose another textField to check if its empty) {

// sign the empty textfield to 0 and add the rest

}

.

.

.

// end of button block
```

To me, this approach doesn't seem a good way either logically and programmatically.

What would be the best approach to achieve this task?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make good use of the *nil coalescing operator* `??` to handle the cases where your textfields are empty or don't contain legal values:

```
let value1 = Int(textfield1.text ?? "") ?? 0
let value2 = Int(textfield2.text ?? "") ?? 0
let value3 = Int(textfield3.text ?? "") ?? 0
let value4 = Int(textfield4.text ?? "") ?? 0
let sum = value1 + value2 + value3 + value4
```

---

Or for a functional approach, collect the `textfield`s in an array literal and use `flatMap` and `reduce` to convert the values and produce the sum:

```
let values = [textfield1, textfield2, textfield3, textfield4].flatMap({$0.text}).flatMap({Int($0)})
let sum = values.reduce(0, +)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to go about this would be to add the textfields to an array and loop through it. This could scale better for more and more textfields. Keep in mind, this example assumes you are using values that could include decimals, but doing this for Int would work just as well.

```
var textField1 = UITextField()
var textField2 = UITextField()
var textField3 = UITextField()
var textField4 = UITextField()
var textFields = [UITextField]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    textFields = [textField1, textField2, textField3, textField4]
}

@IBAction func sumButtonPressed(sender: UIButton){
    var sum = 0.0
    for textField in textFields {
        if let number = Double(textField.text!) { //checks that it is not nil AND a Double
            sum += number
        }
    }
}
```

If you are just using the array of textFields once, (i.e. just in the sumButtonPressed func) then you may want to just initialize the variable in that func like @Adrian said:

```
@IBAction func sumButtonPressed(sender: UIButton){
    let textFields = [textField1, textField2, textField3, textField4]
    var sum = 0.0
    for textField in textFields {
        if let number = Double(textField.text!) { //checks that it is not nil AND a Double
            sum += number
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using this approach, might be better to leave the textFields array as a local variable inside the sumPressed button and populate it when you call sumPressed. `let textFields = [textField1, textField2, textField3, textField4]` at the top of sumPressed instead of having to look all over for what's set where. Purely stylistic, but certainly a lot easier to read.

Comment: @Adrian Okay, I'll edit my post to provide the other method. I guess my method is good if he wanted to have a "quotientButtonPressed" func as well ;)

Comment: that's true, I've a "calculateButton" in my code so I'll put the array inside of the button function.

Comment: @user2066392 It's generally not a good idea to be switching who's answer is the "correct" answer, especially since our answers have not changed. Please just from the beginning choose the answer that is best suited towards solving your problem.